# Разбиение большой игры в одном файле на отдельные файлы

Tags: python, ооп, pygame, рефакторинг

Есть первая итерация игры с одним классом игрока

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    # keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Update
    all_sprites.update()

    # Draw / render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Я хочу вынести код класса игрока в отдельный файл. Да, в общем-то, уже и вынес. Проблема в том, что все равно в main остается кусок кода для создания объекта, группы и добавления в группу

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
```

Эти куски потом разрастутся, так как объектов в игре много. Как бы это все обернуть в методы ещё какого-нибудь класса Game? Какой-то ступор напал, если честно.

Comment: Похоже на, как говорит мой начальник, преждевременный рефакторинг :) Сделайте функцию/класс, в которой будете заполнять игрока и прочие спрайты и вызывайте

Comment: Если интересно, могу выложить весь код игры. В том-то и проблема, что я самоучка и не всё пока получается.

Comment: Как писал выше. Попробуйте сделать, пусть функцию, и из нее возвращайте `all_sprites`. Мб у вас будут разные уровни, тогда для каждого уровня будет свой `all_sprites`

Comment: Вот так нормально будет? https://pastebin.com/H7LpdRsd